# How to transmit data recieved from the product/service buyers to the payment gateway?

Tags: payment-processing

I am willing to know how the process of sending the user account information, payment amount information as well as product/service id information to the payment gateway is conducted.

Where does the data from my last jsp page goes out there in the payment gateway?
How the transmitted information is synchronized and understood when they don't know my thing about the product/service m offering,prices and other flexibilities associated 
or whether they expect me to be preparing a fully accomplished shopping cart and the finally tell them the final amount the buyer has to pay. what actually happens out there?

Comment: This varies from provider to provider. There is no standard api.

Answer (score 0):

Most inline payment processors are willing to just take an amount.  If you're sending the user to an external payment site, you'll normally have to send a cart.  Each different payment processor will most likely give you a schema or webservice to use to send them a cart.  The cart won't stay synchronized, just updated whenever you send that user to the payment processor.